# app.module.ngfactory not being built angular2 aot compiling with webpack

Tags: angular, angular-material2, webpack-2, angular2-aot

I am trying to create a seed that is broken up using this mean stack but also incorporating the angular-cli and material2 currently a w.i.p, but I cannot get my npm build:prod working. and it is not building the app.module.ngfactory

I am not using the ng build I created my own webpack files and own scripts in the package.json file

windows 10,
node @ 6.9.2,
angular-cli @ 2.2.3,
webpack @ 2.2.0-rc.0,
@angular/materail @ 2.0.0-alpha.11-3

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

here is the main.aot.ts

```
import './polyfills';
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from "./public/src/app/app.module.ngfactory";
enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

here is my app.module

```
import 'hammerjs';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import {AppComponent, DialogContent} from './app.component';
// import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from "./shared/header.component";
import { AuthService } from "./auth/auth.service";
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { ErrorService } from './error/error.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // AppComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    AppComponent,
    DialogContent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, ErrorService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and here is a link to my gh
[MEAN2.0_seed](https://github.com/MrCooper42/MEAN2.0_seed)

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Where did you use ngfactory in app.module?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was build when i did the build.

Comment: Also maybe this is part of the issue when I do npm run build (for dev) it will create the bundle.js but the size is over 8 MB